# Error while trying to use <aol-source-cluster> in ngx-openlayers

Tags: javascript, angular, openlayers

When I try to use `<aol-source-cluster>` I get the error: `Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.2/doc/errors/#10 for details.`

My code:

```
<aol-source-cluster *ngIf="isAllMessages" [distance]="distance">
     <aol-source-vector>
        <aol-feature *ngFor="let message of messages">
          <aol-geometry-point>
            <aol-coordinate 
              [x]="message.location.coordinates?.coordinates[0][0]" 
              [y]="message.location.coordinates?.coordinates[0][1]" 
              [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"
            ></aol-coordinate>
          </aol-geometry-point>
        </aol-feature>
      </aol-source-vector>
</aol-source-cluster>
```

The message object look like:

```
{
  location: {
    coordinates: {
      coordinates: [
        53.20749479663824,
        56.8433888
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Could you help me, how to fixed this error?